# Reusing string stream object for string calculations takes lot of time

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have a string stream object which I am reusing .

I use my object like following

```
    stringStreamObj.clear(); stringStreamObj.str(""); <== clear off

    populate(stringStreamObj)

    memcpy(longMemorylocation+offset , stringStreamObj.str().c_str() , stringStreamObj.str().size());
```

The above two tasks are being done continuously in my program .
When I run this in my profiler , my profiler shows that maximum time is being spent in stringStreamObj.str() . On viewing the definition i find that stringStreamObj.str() creates a new string object and hence that is taking time .

How can i reduce this time taking task ?

Comment: You might want to try using `std::string` directly.

Comment: Stringstreams are just slow in my experience. Plus you are creating TWO string objects, as `str()` returns a new string. Store this in a local variable and use that. Alternatively use `strcpy` on one string.

Comment: Just a blind shot, but if performance is bad because of reallocations, you can run your own `stringbuf` implementation with a large-enough buffer.

Comment: Is there a way to get the string pointer directly and a way to get length directly ??? MAy be that might help me . I am using stringstream objecr because i am using it to store int or differetnt tyos of data

Comment: Do you use gcc? It should create new string buffer only if there is a string copy stored somewhere else. The code you provided looks ok in this aspect and should not cause reallocation. Are you sure you do not assign stringStreamObj.str() to another string object somewhere?